# RDS: Not able to fetch events it is showing blank in boto3 describe_events

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, boto3

When I am trying to get rds instance events it is giving blank. But in RDS console it is showing

[image]

But in Boto3 I got below

```
client.describe_events(SourceIdentifier='xxxxcccc',SourceType='db-instance')
{'Events': [], 'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': '-49d7-aa57-940d034bd920', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'x-amzn-requestid': '-a045-49d7-aa57-940d034bd920', 'content-type': 'text/xml', 'content-length': '272', 'date': 'Tue, 10 Jul 2018 07:15:48 GMT'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the docs for `describe_events()` found [here](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/rds.html#RDS.Client.describe_events) "by default, the past hour of events are returned." So if no events occurred within the last hour then it returns an empty list.

I tested this with an instance of my own and calling the function with just

```
rds.describe_events(
    SourceIdentifier='db-instance-identifier',
    SourceType='db-instance'
)
```

returns the same empty response that you got.

But if I actually specify a date range/number of records to return like so:

```
rds.describe_events(
    SourceIdentifier='db-instance-identifier',
    SourceType='db-instance',
    StartTime=datetime(2018, 7, 1),
    EndTime=datetime(2018, 7, 10), 
    MaxRecords=20
)
```

Then I get a response that actually contains the events I'd expect.

Comment: No It does not `>>> client.describe_events(SourceIdentifier='arn:p-prod', SourceType='db-instance',StartTime=datetime.datetime(2018,7,1),EndTime=datetime.datetime(2018,7,9), MaxRecords=20)
{'Events': [], 'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': 'f148a14-a362d673', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'x-amzn-requestid': 'f148a066-7d78-4c14-a362-', 'content-type': 'text/xml', 'content-length': '272', 'date': 'Tue, 10 Jul 2018 09:24:21 GMT'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}}`

Comment: are you using an RDS instance ARN as the `SourceIdentifier` kwarg as it looks like you are in your example? Because it needs to be a database instance identifier

Comment: yes it is instance arn I can not disclose here openly

Comment: okay, so it needs to be a database instance identifier, which is just the name of the RDS instance, without the rest of the ARN stuff.

so instead of  `SourceIdentifier="arn:aws:rds:eu-west-1:123456789012:db:mysql-db"` it **should** be `SourceIdentifier="mysql-db"`